# can't get the resolution right even after installing the nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, resolution

I'm sure my problem might seem simple to many of ya'all but for some reasons I'm stuck with getting the right resolution for my newly installed ubuntu 10.04-64bit and I need some help.
First of all, I don't want to upgrade to newer ubuntu, that's because I need to run some softwares which is well supported by 10.04.

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 in my CPU. After installing, I checked "Hardware Drivers" for my graphics driver. Unfortunately there were no drivers available then. So I installed it from "Synaptic Package Manager". The list of packages I installed are:
-nvidia-current-dev
-nvidia-current
-nvidia-settings
-nvidia-kernel-common
-nvidia-common
-nvidia-current-modaliases
-nvidia-173-modaliases
-nvidia-96-modaliases

Now I can see "NVIDIA accelerated Graphics Driver (version current) [recommended]" and "This driver is activated and currently in use". But then for some reasons I can't get the resolutions right despite a reboot.

Did I miss anything here??

'lspci' command gives me:: 
VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation Device 0e23 (reva1)
This is supposed to show me the driver model no, shouldn't it? Where did I go wrong? What did I miss? In fact I even tried some approaches described in some sites, still wouldn't work.

Any heads-up highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: maybe that is a stupid hint, but did you run nvidia-settings using sudo? (`sudo nvidia-settings` or/and `sudo nvidia-xconfigure`). Also please check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-to-correctly-install-an-nvidia-video-card)

Comment: Thanks so much for ur quick reply. I had already tried them before. Infact, I sorted out this problem. It seems it wasn't related to the computer itself. The problem was lying somewhere else. Since I'm using multiple CPUs for a single monitor -via- KVM switch, the monitor wouldn't recognize the graphics card due to the use of this KVM switch. When I connect my monitor directly to the cpu, wala~~ I got what I needed, a better resolution and seems all good now. I then connected it back again to the KVM switch and still shows no problem.